# Stop service with notification controls' stop button?

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

When I press the stop button, a Throwable exception is thrown.
This is the stacktrace:

```
ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.google.android.exoplayer.stop from system 4132:com.android.systemui/u0a5
    java.lang.Throwable
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:21257)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:21890)
        at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:357)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:5900)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:298)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3538)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)
```

This is the **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.example">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".QApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".article.ArticleActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.Light"/>

        <service
            android:name=".player.PlaybackService">
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Does it have something to do with broadcastIntentLocked?

Comment: are you using android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" in your manifest.?

Comment: @Nitesh No I don't have that in my manifest.

Comment: may you please share your manifest.

Comment: @Nitesh I've added it

Comment: have you registered your receiver anywhere.?

Comment: @Nitesh No, where should I?